# Redirecting nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, hostname

I am running small hosting business and I have 2 servers lets say first server's primary domain is

www.myfirstserver.com and ip address is 111.111.111.111. So I created nameservers for this as

```
ns1.myfirstserver.com with hostname n1.myfirstserver.com pointing 111.111.111.111
and
ns2.myfirstserver.com with hostname ns2.myfirstserver.com pointing 111.111.111.111
```

And, I have a second server and lets say my second server's primary domain is www.mysecondserver.com and ip address is 222.222.222.222. And I created nameservers for this as

```
ns1.mysecondserver.com with hostname ns1.mysecondserver.com pointing 222.222.222.222
and
ns2.mysecondserver.com with hostname ns2.mysecondserver.com pointing 222.222.222.222
```

As of now these 2 are 2 independent servers with no relationship.

Now I want to close the second server and move all the data of second server to first server and I have almost 50 domains in the second server which are pointing to ns1.mysecondserver.com and ns2.mysecondserver.com so rather than asking all my 50 clients to update their nameservers to ns1.myfirstserver.com and ns2.myfirstserver.com

Can I simply update the IP address of the hostname

```
ns1.mysecondserver.com to 111.111.111.111
and
ns2.mysecondserver.com to 111.111.111.111
```

Will this work? If yes, will this perfectly work?

Also, should I add any extra hostname or anything else in WHM?

Comment: You really should have two nameservers. A single nameserver is a single point of failure; if it goes down, _all_ of the sites become inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

No.  This will leave you with mismatched NS and glue records.

Clients will ask the root servers for your NS records and will get the response `222.222.222.222`.  Since this server will not exist any more, that's where they will get stuck.

You will have to update your glue records as well as changing your own NS records (this is managed at your registrar, where you bought your domain).

---

I would ***strongly*** recommend allowing a professional DNS hosting company to host your DNS servers.  Managing your own DNS is difficult even if you really know what you're doing, and I don't think you do.  Most registrars will do this for you for free (or at least included in the cost of the registration).  Companies like Dyn.com specialise in DNS hosting and Amazon have Route53 for very close to no cost.  There are plenty of good options.